# "Aborting aboutToFinish handling." warning with PySide Phonon module

Tags: pyqt, pyside

I'm allowing my workout-clock program to play sounds via the use of the phonon module. For each audio file in my program I create a device (`createPlayer`) and then use the `play()` method on it.

This works absolutely fine except for the fact that playing the sounds repeatedly somehow breaks the player. Sometimes the app works fine throughout an entire program, but sometimes the 'tic' sound of the clock gets disabled.

Every time I run the app, the second time any sound is played, I get the warning `Aborting aboutToFinish handling`. I think this is related.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am also seeing this warning in PyQt4's phonon module, though it doesn't seem to break playback for me.

Comment: i enconter with same warning while playing same audio file second time, i think it creates problem on windows. on ubuntu it works fine.